# ASP.NET Site Templates

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, templates

Are there any good ASP.NET site templates out there? I am looking for something with some very basic features:

- Reusable layout
- Navigation already built in
- Admin Section
- Login Page

I was going to build a template that meets my needs exactly, but thought I would scour around a bit first. If I don't find something that does what I need, at least I could get some ideas.

Webforms or MVC, it doesn't matter.

### EDIT

Not looking for content management system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Asp.Net Design Templates](http://www.asp.net/MVC/Gallery/default.aspx?supportsjs=true) - No clue if they have the code with them or not.

EDIT:
Nevermind, they come with Master Page, CSS files, and images.

Answer (score 0):

do you just want templates. Have you consider using a cms. The umbraco cms is very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good collection of asp.net website template sites.
http://www.m6.net/resources/asp.net-web-templates.aspx